# How can I increment sire codes beyond 'Z' in Laravel?

Tags: excel, laravel, increment

How to increment the sire code like Excel column values (A, B, C, ..., Z, AA, AB, AC, ...)?

Description:

I have a code snippet where I need to increment the sire code in a specific pattern similar to Excel column values. The current code only increments the sire code from A to Z, but I want it to continue incrementing like Excel column values (e.g., A, B, C, ..., Z, AA, AB, AC, ...).

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
            // Retrieve the list of all breeders in descending order based on their breeder codes
            $breeder_sires = BreederSire::orderBy('sire_code', 'desc')->get();

            if ($breeder_sires->count() > 0) {
                // Extract the last sire code from the list
                $last_sire_code = $breeder_sires->first()->sire_code;
        
                // Convert the last sire code to its corresponding numeric value
                $last_sire_code_numeric = ord($last_sire_code) - 64;
        
                // Increment the last sire code numeric value by 1
                $new_sire_code_numeric = $last_sire_code_numeric + 1;
        
                // Convert the incremented sire code numeric value to its corresponding alphanumeric value
                $new_sire_code = chr($new_sire_code_numeric + 64);
        
                // Store the incremented sire code in the sire_code column
                $breeder_sire->sire_code = $new_sire_code;
        
            } else {
                // If there are no existing breeders, use the starting sire code of 'A'
                $new_sire_code = $sire_code;
        
                // Store the starting sire code in the sire_code column
                $breeder_sire->sire_code = $new_sire_code;
            }
        
            // Combine the sire code with the supplier code and blood line to form the new breeder code
            $new_breeder_code = $breeder_sire->sire_code . $supplier_code . $blood_line;

            $breeder_sire->breeder_code = $new_breeder_code;
            $breeder_sire->date_of_birth = $request->input('date_of_birth');
            $breeder_sire->initial_weight = $request->input('initial_weight');
            $breeder_sire->blood_line = $blood_line;
            $breeder_sire->save();
```

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on modifying the code to achieve the desired sire code incrementation pattern. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve like this, with the help of [chr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) function in php

```
function getNameFromNumber($num) {
    $numeric = $num % 26;
    $letter = chr(65 + $numeric);
    $num2 = intval($num / 26);
    if ($num2 > 0) {
        return getNameFromNumber($num2 - 1) . $letter;
    } else {
        return $letter;
    }
}


for($i=0; $i<=100; $i++){
    echo getNameFromNumber($i).",";
}
```

Hope this helps :)